# in reactjs componentWillMount(), how to get which component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html, the function `componentWillMount()` is triggered for both the `server` and the `client`.

how does the `server` know *which* `client` is to be mounted? the `server` might have multiple `client`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: The `server` gets an incoming request by the `client`. The `server` starts generating the Markup for your components and therefore goes through the `componentWillMount()` lifecycle.

Step 2: The `client` receives the markup and the the react components from a seperate JS file (so it knows how to respond to events and can handle rerendering).

Step 3: The `client` renders the React component, except that its markup has already been created in which it saves time, because it doesnt need to do this again.

```
React.render(<Component props="serverprops" />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Step 4: The Components Lifecycle is executed on the client side.

In the above steps you can see that the `server` only 'serves' the files and does an initial render. It is not its responsibility to keep track of all the clients it has served.

You can view an example on this repo:

https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example

I hope this helped

Comment: I think I'm confused by terms server / client. in the context of the doc, I though server would be a component with a child component being a client. am I misunderstanding?

Comment: If it was then the documentation of "componentDidMount()" wouldnt make sense. Rerendering child components would also cause the parent component to rerender and therefor go through its lifecycle. They talk about client and server in terms of client-side and server-side rendering